# How to trigger a batch file in Jenkins without waiting for batch execution results and status

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a Jenkins job which is building /packaging/ deploying .NET project. I use "Clean Before checkout" git property for each build.

Finally, I'm executing a batch file. This batch file scanning sonar Qube MSBuild, c# analysis and update the code quality results. But It is taking a long time and I don't want to increment Jenkins job's total execution time from 1 minute to 5 minutes. Developers are thinking so the deployment is taking a long time and not finished yet.

I want to run this batch file independent from the Jenkins job and don't want to see the console output in Jenkins. How could I do this without creating a new Jenkins job for each Jenkins project (upstream/downstream projects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use the start cmd command,for example:

```
start YourBatch.bat
```

This will open a new CMD window and Jenkins won't wait for result.

**Bare in mind** that if you get an exit code different than 0, it won't fail the build.

Comment: It's working very well on CMD but, not working with Jenkins Execute Windows Batch Command. "call mybatch.bat" is working but "start mybatch.bat" is not working.

Comment: try run "start YourBatch.bat", when in YourBtach.bat the script will be : echo>TEST.txt  .  And see if the file is being created.

Comment: It's working without double quotas. And the other problem was my batch file starting with "@echo off"  I removed it and problem solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: oh...the quotas were for better understanding because it's hard to understand a lot of info in those comments section. you are welcome anyway :)